# Cannot unzip file in android programmatically

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite, unzip

I'm trying to create a mobile dictionary app in android. As a part of the app I'm trying to copy the zipped database file from the assets folder to /data/data/package_name/app_database/file__0/. I'm using the below code to do this.
The below code fails to unzip and copy the database to the desired location, but works fine on second time of app launch.

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try
    {
        String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
    this.copy("0000000000000001.zip","/data/data/"+pName+"/app_database/file__0/");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
}

void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException {
    File CheckDirectory;
    CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
    if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
    { 
        CheckDirectory.mkdir();
    }

    InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
    try {
        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            String outputfilename = ze.getName();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+outputfilename);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                out.write(bytes);             
                baos.reset();
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    }
    finally {
        zis.close();
        in.close();
    }

}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing CheckDirectory.mkdir() with CheckDirectory.mkdirs().